# How do I prevent Screen Time from muting sound?

Tags: sound-volume, ipados, family-sharing, screen-time

We use Screen Time and Family Sharing on my child’s iPad to restrict daily usage of apps.

Annoyingly, when their time runs out while using an app, e.g., Minecraft or Roblox, and I approve additional time, the app’s sound becomes muted. It will remain in a muted state until the app is restarted.

Is this typical behavior? Is there a way to prevent it?